# Getting Error for memory allocation failure?

Tags: 14.04

I am getting an error message as following:

```
pauling@ubuntu:~$ cd /home/pauling/1ionicity/dMBAmmAc
pauling@ubuntu:~/1ionicity/dMBAmmAc$ ./xmvb dMBAmmAcdbovb.xmi
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Allocation would exceed memory limit
pauling@ubuntu:~/1ionicity/dMBAmmAc$
```

Earlier i.e. a day back there was no problem in running a similar program with similar workload input file.

When I checked my system monitor output it shows that about 1.2 GiB of memory is occupied even if my system is idle. I suspect it to be case of memory leakage but am unable to resolve the problem. for your reference I have appended some outputs to check this. Total RAM installed on my PC is 12 GB and OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

```
pauling@ubuntu:~$ ps --sort -rss -eo rss,pid,command | head
  RSS   PID COMMAND
319344 2242 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist-fts
316468 5383 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
239448 2029 compiz
183664 2083 nautilus -n
95164  6091 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/sbin/aptd
64956  2430 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager --no-update --no-focus-on-map
60368  1345 /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
41296  2043 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
36204  1831 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hud/hud-service
pauling@ubuntu:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         11981       8249       3731         14         27       6513
-/+ buffers/cache:       1709      10272
Swap:            0          0          0

pauling@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.9G  4.0K  5.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  1.3M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       290G  103G  173G  38% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            5.9G  156K  5.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   40K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda7       226G  128G   87G  60% /media/pauling/Faraday
/dev/sda5       321G  1.2G  304G   1% /media/pauling/McWeeny
/dev/sda6        33G   48M   31G   1% /media/pauling/b51f7cd1-5937-4474-8929-f51e68c5a791
/dev/sda2        49G   39G   11G  80% /media/pauling/F666864866860997
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and make your question clear by adding more information. (With description of your problem )

Comment: I have edited to the best I could. Hope I am clear about my problem now.

Comment: Can you also add the output of **df -h** and **htop** ? If you don't have htop installed currently you can install by **sudo apt-get install htop** (alternatively you can use **top -n1**)

Comment: I was suspecting from lack of hdd space and memory usage problem but it seems neither of them is possible.